# How to check if intent (activity) contains string in it's package name (Espresso)?

Tags: android, camera, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

I test my app with UI testing and would like to check if the camera app opens.

I have did this with:

```
  @Test
  public void profileImageClickOpensCamera() {

        mIntentsRule.getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(mIntentsRule.getActivity(), ProfileActivity.class));

        onView(withId(R.id.circleProfileImage)).perform(click());
        intended(toPackage("com.android.camera"));

    }
```

**It is working fine on most device**s, however if I rain it on SAMSUNG Galaxy S8, which has **"com.sec.android.app.camera" package of it's camera app, the test fails.**

My question is, how could I check with espresso that **the package contains the word "camera" ?**

It's not the best solution because a device's camera app's package name could be anything, but even better then what I got know.

**So I would like to do something like:**

```
intended(StringContains(toPackage("com.android.camera")));
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm new to testing, but can't you test the intent action instead of package? Something like `intended(hasAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE))` or `intended(hasAction(equalTo(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)))`?

Comment: Well, nice, can you add this as an answer?

Comment: Nice! I made an answer =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the intent action instead of package.

Something like `intended(hasAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE))` or  `intended(hasAction(equalTo(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)))` should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation and I've managed to solve it like this:

```
PackageManager packageManager = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getPackageManager();
        String pack = resultData.resolveActivity(packageManager).getPackageName();

intended(toPackage(pack));
```

In my situation I had an activity with a button which opens the camera, lets you take a picture and returns with it in your activity. The full code of this test would be:

```
@Test
public void testCameraIntent() {
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getResources(),
                R.drawable.husky);

        // Build a result to return from the Camera app
        Intent resultData = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        resultData.putExtra("data", icon);
        Instrumentation.ActivityResult result = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData);

        PackageManager packageManager = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getPackageManager();
        String pack = resultData.resolveActivity(packageManager).getPackageName();

        // Stub out the Camera. When an intent is sent to the Camera, this tells Espresso to respond
        // with the ActivityResult we just created
        intending(toPackage(pack)).respondWith(result);

        // Now that we have the stub in place, click on the button in our app that launches into the Camera
        onView(withId(R.id.btn_takePicture)).perform(click());

        intended(toPackage(pack));
    }
```

And this is the result :-) the image with Husky dog is a local image I've set to be sent in my custom ActivityResult: 
[image]